# javascript: catch any click event on current page and prevent navigation?

Tags: javascript

```
function stopNav() {
var han;
evt = window.event

  if (evt) {
  var elem = evt.target ? han = evt.target : evt.srcElement && (han = evt.srcElement)
       if (evt.type=="click") {  
          evt.preventDefault();alert('stopped navigation');
      }
  }
}
```

I want to prevent the possibility of user navigating away from the page. sometimes if they click on a link or a button or even a  element, it will navigate to another page. I want to prevent this from happening. If it's some ajax event happening on the page, that's fine.

Comment: So you want to prevent the navigation on `click` event but allow in case of `ajax`. is that it??

Comment: @Rohit416 yes it should only stop if navigation starts to happen. i want to know if i can do this without defining `onbeforeunload` handler

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment which says

> @Rohit416 yes it should only stop if navigation starts to happen. i want to know if i can do this without defining `onbeforeunload` handler

I must point out that you can't. There's no other single somewhat reliable way to detect when your page is being unloaded, nor is there **ANY** way to prevent users from leaving your page. Think about other ways they could leave, such as typing a new address in the address bar, or clicking a bookmark etc.

`onbeforeunload` is just a way of giving users a suggestion that they shouldn't be leaving at the moment, but the decision is still in their hands.

If you prevent users from clicking links on your page, then what's the point in having links in the first place?